# $(\mathbb{Q}^2,+,\cdot)$ is a field, if $p \neq q^2$ for all $q \in \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $p \in \mathbb{Q}$ with $p \geq 0$. Consider the binary operations $+,\cdot: \mathbb{Q}^2 \times \mathbb{Q}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}^2$, given by $(a,b) + (c,d) \mapsto (a+c,b+d)$ and $(a,b) \cdot (c,d) \mapsto (ac + pbd, ad + bc)$ for all $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Q}$. I want to show the following implication: if $p \neq q^2$ $\forall q \in \mathbb{Q}$, then $(\mathbb{Q}^2,+,\cdot)$ is a field.

I have already proven that $(\mathbb{Q}^2,+)$ is an abelian group and that $\cdot$ is commutative. I have even proven that $(\mathbb{Q}^2,+,\cdot)$ is a commutative unital ring. The only piece missing are multiplicative inverses, I guess.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It doesn't matter if it works for some perfect square. What you need to proof is that whenever $p$ is not a perfect square, then $(\mathbb Q^2$ is a field.

Comment: Yes, and I am lacking an idea how to tackle this.

Comment: If this is a field, it would be a quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. Those look like $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ for some $d$ not a square. Now write out the multiplication in this $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$.

Comment: Typos in your $(a,b)+(b,c)=(a+b,c+d)$.

Comment: Actually, for $p=0$ is not a field, although that doesn't matter, since you are asked for the other implication

Comment: Consider the function $\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q\to\Bbb R$ defined by $(a,b)\mapsto a+\sqrt pb$.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comments. I figured it out and fixed the mistakes in the original post.

Comment: You have not used the assumption that $p$ is not a square. Did you try $p=2$?

Comment: I really don't think you want $(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+b,c+d)$, Reikiri.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @jjagmath you said it is not a field for p = 0, but then I should have zero divisors shouldn't I? The multiplication boils down to $(a,b)\cdot(c,d) \mapsto (ac,ad+bc)$. Then for $(a,b) \neq (0,0)$ I know that $ac = 0$, thus $a = 0$ and $ad = bc$, thus $b = ad/c$. But as $a$ is supposed to be zero, how can I have zero divisors, then? I think I still miss a piece here.

Comment: @Reikiri $(0,1) \cdot (0,1) = (0,0)$

Comment: Thanks, of course.